# Mysql database column constraint error

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem and I would really love if I could have some help. I am using a php application to interact with the database. I have a database, which is working perfectly. However when I backed it up and moved it to another PC it started to act up. It is identical to the original. I have a table called `Authorize`, and a column `authorized` with a default not being null, however when I try to update the authorized column following message comes up (On the original system it still works fine, I can't seem to find the problem).

```
Error: Column 'authorized' cannot be null
sql: update `authorized` set `authorized` = :authorized where `authorized_id` = :identity_id;

arr_sql_param: Array
(
[:identity_id] => 22
[:authorized] => 
)

Sent From: update_grid()
```

Comment: Modify your error reporting to produce a [backtrace](http://us.php.net/debug_backtrace) after an error, inspect the backtrace to see what calls this function with bogus data, fix that. It's impossible to say what is wrong with this little information (though for some reason I suspect `register_globals`).

Comment: So if register_globals is the problem how would I address this?

Comment: please show the actual code where `arr_sql_param` is initialized/set.

Comment: @Kaii the code can be seen here http://lazymofo.wdschools.com/code/2012-06-30/_show_source.php I would appreciate if you could look through and tell me what you think the error is, Im new to this seeing that it works perfectly on my 1st PC and now since i transferred it its malfunctioning

Comment: @dames: I would suggest making dumps of both DB schemas, outputs of `phpinfo()`, [MySQL's sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html), PHP/MySQL versions, and comparing them. There should be a difference between them somewhere.

Comment: @DCoder indeed, the logic of `cast_value()` is truly awesome and may deserve a post on TheDailyWTF

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code:

```
public function sql_update() {
    ...
    // make sql statement from key and values in $_POST data
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
        $sql_set .= "`$key` = :$key, "; 
        $sql_param[":$key"] = $this->cast_value($val, $key);
    ...
    // posted values are saved here for pdo execute
    $sql_param = array();
    $sql_param[':identity_id'] = $identity_id;
    ...
    $sql_final = "update `$this->table` set $sql_set where `$this->identity_name` = :identity_id;";
    ...
```

And the error:

> Error: Column 'authorized' cannot be null
>   sql: update `authorized` set `authorized` = :authorized where `authorized_id` = :identity_id;

I realize that indeed `:authorized` is not set or included in the SQL statement explicitly.

Which leads to two possible conclusions:

1. When the column cannot be NULL in this environment but the same code works fine on your development system (your PC), then the database scheme may be different on those two systems.

   On the new environment, the `authorized` column in table `authorized` is defined `NOT NULL` while on your dev environment you don't have this constraint.

   Compare `SHOW CREATE TABLE authorized` from both systems to see if this is true.
2. since the column value for `authorized` is coming from the `$_POST` array .. is it possible that it's just not posted by the browser for some reason? Can't find a reason for that in your code, though.

Comment: do you have any suggestions in the case where it mite be the browser, because even another section to the application for some reason is not being entered in to the database from a php form I created, and as i said on my development system it works fine

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions and nothing same old, I have tried creating the database from scratch and still nothing, its a puzzling situation, any more suggestions?